# Pop does not work like it should - the start item isn't going to be dequeued

Tags: c, pointers, queue

I have a little problem with my C Code. I want to implement a simple queue with some functions, but the pop function doesn't work. The start item isn't going to be dequeued. I just don't know why. It be so nice of you if you could help me.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct item{
  struct item* toNext;
  int value;
};
void printQueue(struct item* start){
  if(start == NULL){
      printf("\n");
    return;
  }
  else{
    printf("%d\n", start->value);
    printQueue(start->toNext);
  }
}
int pop(struct item* start){
  if(start == NULL){
    return -1;
  }
  else{
    int tmp = start->value;
    start = NULL;
    return tmp;
  }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  struct item* beginning;
  struct item* current;
  struct item* next;
  current = (struct item*) malloc(sizeof(struct item)); 
  current->value = 1;
  current->toNext = NULL;
  beginning = current;
  int i;
  for(i = 2; i <= 4; i++){
    next = (struct item*) malloc(sizeof(struct item)); 
    next-> value = i;
    next-> toNext = NULL;
    current->toNext = next;
    current = next; // TODO

  }
  printQueue(beginning);
  int tmp = pop(beginning);
  printf("%d\n",tmp);
  printQueue(beginning);

  return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
1
2
3
4

1
1
2
3
4
```

Although it should be:

```
1
2
3
4

1

2
3
4
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: You pop() function receives a copy of the pointer to the head of the queue. (You can also think of it as receiving a read-only "copy" of the whole queue).  But a pop function needs to modify the queue.  So you're going to have to rearrange things.

Comment: So any changes to that copy are **not** reflected in the original (in main).

Comment: Why do you explicitly allocate a node for the queue in `main`? All queue interaction should go through the queue interface, i.e. the functions and an empty queue is repesented by a head pointer that's `NULL`. (Ah, I see now: you have no `push` function.)

Comment: And if you fixed that, you would still have the problem that `start = NULL;` would be throwing away the whole list, not just the first entry on the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify your beginning pointer inside your pop function, you'll need to pass not just a pointer, but a pointer to a pointer, so that you can modify not only the data that is pointed to, but the pointer itself. So, your function signature would need to become:

```
int pop(struct item** start)
```

This will require modifying your code a little bit, since you need to dereference once to get to your beginning pointer, and twice to get to the actual data. Also, setting the beginning pointer to null will erase your whole list. You'll have to set your beginning pointer to the next item in the list. Your function would end up looking something like this:

```
int pop(struct item** start){
  // Dereference once to get to beginning pointer
  if(*start == NULL){
    return -1;
  }
  else{
    // Dereference, then use arrow to get pointer to data, then data itself
    int tmp = (*start)->value;
    // Move beginning pointer to next item
    *start = (*start)->next;
    return tmp;
  }
}
```

Please be advised that this can cause a memory leak if you don't also store a pointer for the original pointer given to you by `malloc()` since you'd be losing track of memory.